# Cannot pop up dialog for user to select options, with HTTP call, during AR Session

Tags: android, xamarin, asynchronous

During the `AR session (ARCore in Xamarin.Android, with OpenGL)`, a pop up dialog cannot show up.

My **Xamarin.Android** form now let user to place a object in the `AR Session`.

A conformation flow would like to add as below:

1. User click in AR session, compute the real world coordinate with GPS.
2. Consume a HTTP call to check if any reference object can be found from database.
3. If yes, pop up a dialog for user to confirm the object.

Tried to add the routine in different stage:

- OnSingleTap --> No OpenGL context existed
- OnDrawFrame --> ignored by the flow

Tried to run Async thread in sync:

- **Task tm = Task.Run(async () => await Func_Name  --> ignored**

Comment: Do you have a try with `RunOnUiThread(() => { //Pop Up Method });`? When background trask finishs,UI should be updated in UI Thread.

Comment: The RunOnUIThread did works, Thanks! 
Further supplement, it need to set the AR update model to "when  Dirty" instead "Continue" also.

Comment: Okey, may I update this for answer ?

Comment: Yes, please. Thanks you

Comment: Great, glad you solved it ! I have updated answer, thanks for marking in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> During the AR session (ARCore in Xamarin.Android, with OpenGL), a pop up dialog cannot show up.

When background trask finishs,UI should be updated in UI Thread.

```
RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    //Here is your UI code.
});
```

Here is the [Activity.RunOnUiThread Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.activity.runonuithread?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) .